# Is there any legitimate reason for duplicate ping packets over a single hop?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ping

I'm doing a single hop to a WiFi AP. There's only one AP serving this SSID, and I'm pinging it directly, and getting hilarity like:

```
64 bytes from 192.168.1.0: icmp_seq=87 ttl=32 time=112.501 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.0: icmp_seq=87 ttl=32 time=129.409 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from 192.168.1.0: icmp_seq=87 ttl=32 time=243.003 ms (DUP!)
```

(our connection to it also dies all the time.)

Is there some logical explanation? (The normal, "got duplicated by the network" stuff doesn't seem to hold well over a single link. Personally, I think it's time we retire this Netgear, and I'm thinking of using this as proof.)

(at the moment, too, this is happening consistently. I'm getting pretty close to 100% of my pings having duplicates over several minutes of continuous pinging.)

Comment: I have lots of ideas, but need more details. What's your subnet mask? Are you pinging the network address (all zero bits in the host portion of the address)? If so, does the same thing happen when you ping a normal unicast host address? Have you double-checked that all your devices are using the right subnet mask? Have you run tcpdump to see if those dups are coming from different MAC addresses? Do you always get triples like this? Is either device's Wi-Fi interface in promiscuous mode?

Comment: 192.168.1.0 is not a valid unicast IP address so you are either running pinging with a -b for broadcast, or you should have gotten the message `Do you want to ping broadcast? Then -b` instead of ping results. What OS are you using (the output looks like linux)? Either way, unless you are pinging a unicast address, you run the likelihood of recieving multiple responses for each datagram you send.

Comment: @FrankThomas You're probably right because he's probably on 192.168.1.0/24, but 192.168.1.0 can be a valid unicast address if he's on, say, 192.168.0.0/23.

Comment: @FrankThomas: re "192.168.1.0 is not a valid unicast IP address" <-- you should put this as an answer, because that's spot on! I was indeed intending to ping the router!

Comment: @Spiff sadly, I'm on OS X, and I don't think BSD ping outputs the "Do you want to ping broadcast?" message. (It didn't, for me, even though I mistakenly am.)

Comment: @Thanatos Frank hasnt returned so you should add an answer yourself and mark it as resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @FrankThomas noted in a comment:

> 192.168.1.0 is not a valid unicast IP address so you are either running pinging with a -b for broadcast, or you should have gotten the message `Do you want to ping broadcast?` Then -b instead of ping results. What OS are you using (the output looks like linux)? Either way, unless you are pinging a unicast address, you run the likelihood of recieving multiple responses for each datagram you send

I was in fact pinging the broadcast address, when I intended to be pinging the router. (Routers are usually, and in my case, the `.1` address, not `.0` address.) The multiple results are likely the multiple hosts.

The last note is that I didn't get the "Do you want to ping broadcast?" warning that Frank notes; I believe that is a GNU `ping` warning, whereas I'm on OS X, so I'm assuming BSD's `ping` does not output that.